# Last Minute Extension of Chinese M Visa

Tags: visas, china, visa-extensions, russian-citizens, working-visas

My Russian girlfriend has a Chinese M visa and is currently living in Beijing, working for a school via some type of agency (the school pays the agency, which takes a cut, and then pays my girlfriend).

Her visa expires in two days.

The agency first told her yesterday that she would need to leave China and then re-apply in Russia for a new M visa. However, today they told her that she can go to Harbin and renew the M visa there, in country.

Multi-part question:

Is it possible to extend an M visa while in-country so close to expiration? From what I read she needs to have done it at least 7 days before it expires.

Can the renewal happen in any city/region, or does it have to be in the one she lives/works in (Beijing)?

Finally, is it possible for her to go by herself and get a tourist visa (or any other type) so that she then has additional time to figure out the M visa?

Comment: as ultimate chance I think she can go to Hong Kong and get an L or M visa

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as her going back to Russia to do that (albeit maybe a bit cheaper going to HK)?

Comment: Harbin has special agreement for russian citiezens. If your gf has an invitation from chinese side, she can get visa in Harbin. It will takes couple hours.

Comment: @MikkaRin that's awesome to hear! Do you know of any sites or links with documentation about that?

Comment: @Matthew Herbst I know information only about touristic visa. But I will try to find info for your situation

Comment: @MikkaRin I would appreciate that - I've been looking for information about it and can't seem to find anything